# How to pre-load SASS custom utilities (variables and mixins) with webpack

Tags: sass, webpack, node-sass, sass-loader

I am loading my utilities and assets in `base.scss` like so

```
@import "_variables";
@import "_mixins";
...
```

I have tons of modules in my application and we are doing so many changes in these modules.

so importing the `base.scss` in the header of each of the scss files is causing so much trouble and seems very redundant.

I tried using sass's [includePaths](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#includepaths) but it didn't help as it only resolves the @import declarations.

Is there any way that I can auto import my utilities without having to @import it manually in each file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loader will do the job 
https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader
by adding this to your webpack config
`sassResources: [ './path/to/vars.scss', './path/to/mixins.scss' ]`

### Update


check the implementation out in action in [this boilerplate](https://github.com/AymanJitan/webpackular/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L29)

Answer (score 3):

In Webpack 5, this is how I did it:

```
{
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    additionalData: `@import "${__dirname}/src/int/css/_mixins.scss";`
},
```

Simply add the path to your e.g. SCSS Mixin or variable file to "additionalData".

Comment: Works a treat! Importing my globals into a single `_global.scss` and adding it like this.